# How to inherit from a class with mandatory argument in ctor?

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

It seems that if we create a class `B` that inherits from class `A`, `A`'s constructor is called when `B` is being created. This leads to the following problem - `A` may have a mandatory parameter in its ctor (for use during instantiation), and so running the following:

```
A <- setRefClass("A", 
    methods = list(
        initialize = function(mandatoryArg) {
            print(mandatoryArg)
        }
    )
)

B <- setRefClass("B", contains = "A")
```

I get the error

```
Error in .Object$initialize(...) : 
  argument "mandatoryArg" is missing, with no default
```

This seems very strange - why is this happening and what can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

The implicit requirement is that the constructor with no arguments (e.g., `A()`) succeeds, so provide a default value for `mandatoryArg`

```
A <- setRefClass("A", 
    methods = list(
        initialize = function(mandatoryArg=character()) {
            print(mandatoryArg)
        }
    )
)
```

or (recommended) avoid using the `initialize` method for construction but instead define a user-friendly wrapper

```
.A <- setRefClass("A", fields=list(mandatoryField="character"))

A <- function(mandatoryArg, ...) {
    if (missing(mandatoryArg))
        stop("'mandatoryArg' missing")
    .A(mandatoryField=mandatoryArg, ...)
}

.B <- setRefClass("B", contains="A")

B <- function()
    .B()
```

or  `B <- function() .B(mandatoryField="foo")` or `B <- function() .B(A("mandatoryField"))`